# How to find context in a widget? It is undefined

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying to find a way on how I can put a navigation in "Widget CardUI" because I want it to redirect the user to another page when they click on it. However, when I try to put the usual     Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>PageName()));", it tells me that the context is undefined.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.white),
              onPressed: ()
              {Navigator.pop(context);
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>homepage()));}),
          title: Text("Creator's Club"),
          backgroundColor: Color(0xff2657ce),
          elevation: 0,),
        body: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Visual Arts', style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xff2657ce),
                    fontSize: 27,
                  ),),
                  Text('Choose which course you want to study.', style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
                      fontSize: 20
                  ),),
                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                  Expanded(
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            coursesList.length == 0 ? Center(child: Text("Loading...", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),)): ListView.builder(
                                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                itemCount: coursesList.length,
                                itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                                  return CardUI(coursesList[index].courseName, coursesList[index].teacher, coursesList[index].category);
                                }
                            )
                          ]
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ]
            )
        )
    );
  }
}

Widget CardUI (String courseName, String teacher, String category){
      return Card(
        elevation: 1,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        color: Color(0xffd3defa),
        child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(1),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        width: 50,
                        height: 50,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xffd3defa),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(17)),
                        ),
                        child: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.star_border_rounded,
                            color: Color(0xff2657ce),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 15,),
                      Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                                child: InkWell(
                                  onTap: () {},
                                  child: Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Text(courseName,
                                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                                      SizedBox(height: 5),
                                      Text(teacher, style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 15, color: Colors.grey)),
                                      SizedBox(height: 5),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                )
                            )
                          ]
                      )
                    ]
                )
              ],
            )
        ),
      );
  }
```

Additionally, is there a way on how I can put an if else condition in the Inkwell onTap? In my code, a bunch of courses are being displayed from realtime database and I want to click on just one of it. In my current code, the Inkwell applies to all the cards being displayed but I just want it to be on one. Are there any alternatives besides using Inkwell?

Comment: Either use StateFulWidget or pass the context from build function to card function, which is having onTap

Comment: @ॐRakeshKumar Hey, it worked out. Thanks! Btw, do you know if there is anyway I can click on one card that has the courseName "ABCD"?

Comment: you can do something like this onTap: (){
    if(courseName=='ABCD'){
    //Do as per your requirement
    }
    else {
    
    }
    },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call

```dart
onPressed: () {
  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>homepage()));
},
```

without `pop` before.

Comment: Hey, it worked out. Thanks! Btw, do you know if there is anyway I can click on one card that has the courseName "ABCD"?

Comment: If you have to click on an element and handle `onTap` or other action, wrap widget with `InkWell` or `GestureDetector` and add action method.